# Как ускорить время выполнения программы в VB

Tags: шифрование, vb.net

Программа которая "шифрует" файл. Открывает файл в формате байтов и переписывает их значение на 10 больше, если значение больше 255, записывает остаток от деления на 256. Вторая часть "расшифровывает" файл по такому же принципу. С фото в 4к производит "шифровку" или "расшифровку" за 6-7 секунд. Но если делать тоже самое с видео весом 1.5 гигабайта, то процесс займёт 11,5 дней. Как ускорить время выполнения программы. Язык VB.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.Write("Введите тип операции, шифровка (0), дешифровка (1) - ")
        Dim z As Integer = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Введите имя файла - ")
        Dim x As String = Console.ReadLine()
        If z = 0 Then
            arx(x)
        Else
            dea(x)
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub arx(a As String)
        FileOpen(1, a, OpenMode.Binary)
        Dim b(FileLen(a)) As Byte
        Dim t As Integer
        For i = 1 To UBound(b)
            FileGet(1, b(i))
        Next
        FileClose(1)

        For i = 1 To UBound(b)
            t = b(i)
            b(i) = (t + 10) Mod 256
        Next

        FileOpen(1, a, OpenMode.Output)
        FileClose(1)
        FileOpen(1, a, OpenMode.Binary)
        For i = 1 To UBound(b)
            FilePut(1, b(i))
        Next
        FileClose()
    End Sub

    Sub dea(a As String)
        FileOpen(1, a, OpenMode.Binary)
        Dim b(FileLen(a)) As Byte
        Dim t As Integer
        For i = 1 To UBound(b)
            FileGet(1, b(i))
        Next
        FileClose(1)

        For i = 1 To UBound(b)
            t = b(i)
            If b(i) < 10 Then
                b(i) = t + 246
            Else
                b(i) -= 10
            End If
        Next

        FileOpen(1, a, OpenMode.Output)
        FileClose(1)
        FileOpen(1, a, OpenMode.Binary)
        For i = 1 To UBound(b)
            FilePut(1, b(i))
        Next
        FileClose()
    End Sub


End Module
```

Процедура arx() - Шифрует
Процедура dea() - Расшифровывает

Я подозреваю, скорость можно увеличить переписав программу на C или сделать многопоточность. Как сделать программу многопоточной не знаю.

Comment: Читать-писать-обрабатывать надо блоками, а не побайтно. Причём блоками вменяемого размера (для Windows я рекомендую 1-4 Мбайт, дальнейшее увеличение обычно не ускоряет процесс), попытка прочитать побайтно в память весь файл на полтора гектара - это само по себе бредятина.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй прочитать файл одним потоком, это как минимум должно сократить время чтения файла и его кеширования как массив.

```
''' <summary>
''' Загрузить файл в Byte()
''' </summary>
''' <param name="filePath"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Shared Function LoadFileAsByte(filePath As String) As Byte()
    If System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then 'Если файл есть, то прочитать
        Dim readStream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath)
        Dim bFile(0 To CInt(readStream.Length - 1)) As Byte 'файл
        readStream.Read(bFile, 0, bFile.Length - 1)
        readStream.Dispose()
        Return bFile
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Сохранить Byte() в файл.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="fileData"></param>
''' <param name="filePath"></param>
''' <param name="processKill"></param>
Public Shared Sub SaveFile(fileData As Byte(), filePath As String, Optional ByVal processKill As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal hidden As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal archive As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal [readOnly] As Boolean = False)
    If fileData Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim dirPath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(filePath).DirectoryName 'Имя корневого каталога
    CreateDir(dirPath) 'Проверить наличие каталога, создать

    DeleteFile(filePath, processKill, True) 'Проверить наличие файла и удалить 
    If IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then 'Файл найден
        Throw New Exception($"Unable to delete file. Path: {filePath}")
    End If

    Using fileCreate As FileStream = IO.File.Create(filePath)
        fileCreate.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length)
    End Using

    'https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getattributes?view=net-5.0
    If hidden Or archive Or [ReadOnly] Then
        Dim attributes = IO.File.GetAttributes(filePath)
        If hidden Then IO.File.SetAttributes(filePath, attributes Or FileAttributes.Hidden) : attributes = IO.File.GetAttributes(filePath) 'Hide the file.
        If archive Then IO.File.SetAttributes(filePath, attributes Or FileAttributes.Archive) : attributes = IO.File.GetAttributes(filePath) 'Archive the file.
        If [readOnly] Then IO.File.SetAttributes(filePath, attributes Or FileAttributes.ReadOnly) 'ReadOnly the file.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Зачем читать файл в память? Это ничего не даст, только расход памяти...

Comment: Теоретически, если прочитать файл целиком, обработать массив и также - потоком его записать, то должен быть профит. Надеюсь мы скоро это узнаем)